# Getting formula & graph from locatable points

Tags: plotting, dynamic

My goal is to, firstly, get formula-I think Findformula function might be used- from locatable points(for example from 10 locatable points as below),and secondly,superimpose the graph of formula over the points.I tried it as far as below,referencing docs. How to modify further to get formula and superimposed the graph of it?

```
DynamicModule[{pt = Table[{x, 1}, {x, 10}]}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    ListLinePlot[pt]
   ], Dynamic[pt]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "FindFormula" is too time consuming. Therefore, need another way. For a first example we choose "Interpolation" to get a function from the data points.

```
pts0 = Table[{i, 0}, {i, 1, 11}];
AppendTo[funs, 1];
Manipulate[fu = Interpolation[pts]; 
 Plot[fu[x], {x, 1, 10}, Epilog -> Point[pts], 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
 , {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Another possibility is, to choose some symbolic form for your function. For an example, I choose a sin/cos basis, but you can choose any other suitable functions. With this basis, a fast linear fit is then made:

```
pts0 = Table[{i, 0}, {i, 1, 11}];
funs = Table[{Sin[i x], Cos[i x]}, {i, 1, 5}] // Flatten;
AppendTo[funs, 1];
```

With this we can create a manipulate that shows the points and the function:

```
Manipulate[fu = LinearModelFit[pts, funs, x] // Normal; 
 Plot[fu, {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> Point[pts], PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
 , {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]
```

[image]